# Reusing the instance of CKEditor in the Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: ckeditor

First, I create an instance of CKEditor named 'richEditor' in a webPage.
Second, upon a button click I am making  ajax call, which returns  html data, and showing it in a jquery UI dialog.Then I am  copying the HTML of 'richEditor' instance  already present in the webpage and  pasting it in a div in the dialog.
But the reused 'richEditor'  instance does not  work.Any button click in the editor is throwing javascript error and neither the textarea nor the source text area is editable.

Any help or thought is really  appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot basically copy the HTML of the editor and reuse it. First of all, DOM structure of the instance is strictly connected to the JS code driving the editor (and vice versa). It's much deeper than plain HTML. The second reason is that the editor you use is based on the `iframe`, which cannot be copied preserving its content.

In other words: You have to create another instance of the editor to run it somewhere else. Please refer to the [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) and API docs to know more about [CKEDITOR.replace()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace), [CKEDITOR.appendTo()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-appendTo) and [CKEDITOR.destroy()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy).